# Structures within objects: solving segmentation fault issues

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with segmentation faults when trying to access a class member, which is a structure, from within a class function.  I assume I am declaring this wrong somewhere, but I can't see what the problem is.  I have tried many variations with no luck so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**program.h:**

```
struct ButtonState {
  int analog_pin;
};

class LEDGarden {

 public:
  ButtonState *the_state;
  LEDGarden(void) {}

  void init(void);
  void initButtons(void);
};
```

**program.cpp:**

```
#include "program.h"

void LEDGarden::init(void) {

  ButtonState *the_state = new ButtonState();

  the_state->analog_pin = 5;
  initButtons();

}

void LEDGarden::initButtons(void) {
  // The problem happens here.
  the_state->analog_pin = 5;
}

int main() {
  LEDGarden garden;
  garden.init();
}
```

The segmentation fault happens when I try to make an assignment in the structure in the function `initButtons`.  I am at quite a loss as to what the problem is.

Note that this program works fine for me when using gcc so long as I don't use the `-O2` flag.  Using clang I get the segfault regardless of the compilation flags.

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to store a pointer rather than an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LEDGarden` has a pointer to a `ButtonState` which you never set.

The `init` method shadows the member variable with a local of the same name (so the member variable is not set when you go to use it). try

```
void LEDGarden::init(void) {
  this->the_state = new ButtonState();
  the_state->analog_pin = 5;
  initButtons();

}
```

What you should probably do is get rid of `init()` and make it a constructor.

The different behaviors probably depends on what the member variable is set to null or random memory location (which may be "good" or "bad", but never "right" ;-)